# R: Trouble accessing/extracting values from XML

Tags: r, xml, import

For the last 4 hours I have tried accessing some values in  xml file through R without any luck, and now I am all empty for new ideas.

This is the xml file: http://opcom.ro/order_book/OBK-30XROOPCOM-----C-2016-08-19.xml

I'm trying to get all Qty values in //OrderTimeSeries//SupplyCurve//Period//Interval//Point, so that the first entry would be  0, the next 0 and then 23 and so on.

I have tried stuff like:

```
library(XML)    

doc <- xmlParse("http://opcom.ro/order_book/OBK-30XROOPCOM-----C-2016-08-19.xml")

qty <- unlist(xpathApply(doc,"//OrderTimeSeries//SupplyCurve//Period//Interval//Point",xmlvalue))
```

I think this would work if the xml was written like

```
<Qty>"0.00000000000"<Qty/>
```

But I dont know how to extract the value when it's written inside the <> with v = 0,00000000000.

Comment: On StackOverflow you need to provide what is called an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve not just links to an XML document.  We can give you so much better help if you show an example of what is working fine, with any output, and what does not work, again with the output.  In the process of creating that you might solve your own problem, but if not, given the fuller information, we can help.

Comment: _"does not look like the one's I'm used to"_. It has nodes, attributes and values. Kinda looks like every other XML file I've ever seen.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to both stackoverflow and the XML format. I tried adding some more text to the description. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a node `<Pos="##"/>` in each of the `<Interval>` "records". I suspect that's important data to identify each time series differently and you're kinda just throwing it away with that rough selector.

You can attack the problem in a straightforward way:

- find each interval

  - extract `Pos`
  - find `Point`

    - extract the sub-values of `Point`

and build a `data.frame` along the way:

```
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

doc <- read_xml("http://opcom.ro/order_book/OBK-30XROOPCOM-----C-2016-08-19.xml")

names_and_values <- function(x) {
  names <- xml_name(xml_find_all(x, ".//*"))
  vals <- as.numeric(xml_attr(xml_find_all(x, ".//*"), "v"))
  df <- rbind.data.frame(vals)
  setNames(df, names)
}

pos_and_points <- function(x) {
  pos <- as.numeric(xml_attr(xml_find_first(x, ".//Pos"), "v"))
  xml_find_all(x, ".//Point") %>% 
    map_df(names_and_values) -> df
  df$pos <- pos
  df
}

xml_find_all(doc, ".//OrderTimeSeries/SupplyCurve/Period/Interval") %>% 
  map_df(pos_and_points) -> df

dplyr::glimpse(df)
## Observations: 5,316
## Variables: 4
## $ Qty         <dbl> 0.0, 0.0, 23.0, 23.0, 26.5, 26.5, 56.8, 56.8, 150.5, 150.5, 171.5, 171....
## $ PriceAmount <dbl> -5.000000e+02, -2.500000e+01, -2.500000e+01, -2.235536e+01, -2.235536e+...
## $ SeqNr       <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...
## $ pos         <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,...
```

Comment: thank you so much. That was a huge help. I can easily follow your main idea, and your code is very readable. I haven't heard of the `map_df` from `purr` before,- I will use that package from now on.